# Resizing images on the server

Tags: python, django, image-processing, image-resizing, django-imagekit

We just implemented a feature where our users can upload photos. We are re-sizing what the user has uploaded into thumbnail and an 800x600 "display" size.

The problem we are having is that this operation seems to be taking up a lot of memory on our server. We are using Django-imagekit to do this and there seems to be [documented problems with excessive memory usage](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit/issues/63).

We are running django on a Heroku server. In case this factors in, we are using postgresql for data and elasticsearch for search as well.

- Is there a better library that we should be using for this?
- Or is there a completely different strategy for handling user photos on the
  server that we should consider?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Is there any reason why this needs to be handled within Django at all? (Do you need to be able to serve the resized photos immediately?) If not, breaking free from Django would allow you to use any other folder-watching, automated tool you prefer.

Comment: @Mr. Dave - No, I don't think it needs to be. I think these are just the tools that we grabbed first. Just not sure what the next one we should try is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what `django-imagekit` offers but you could just use PIL and when saving an upload image resize it to the sizes that you need.

http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

Answer (score 2):

I have used and it works well [PythonMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/) and you could also try [wand](http://dahlia.github.com/wand/) it is a ctypes-based ImagedMagick binding library for Python

Answer (score 1):

I have used [gd2](http://www.boutell.com/gd/) with ruby, which works pretty well. It's written in C, so it is fast and shouldn't take a whole lot of memory. It looks like there are [Python bindings](http://nets.ucar.edu/nets/intro/staff/mitchell/gd-ref.html).